# Could someone please explain double-angle identities?

Tags: trigonometry

I don't understand how to do maths, mostly because I don't understand why formulae work they way they do, or the reasoning behind equations, etc.

I tried to explain the $\sin(2\theta)$ double-angle identity to myself but failed:

Hypothetically if:

$$\text{opp} = 1 \qquad \text{adj} = 2 \qquad \text{hyp} = 3$$

then

$$\begin{align*}
\sin(2\theta) &= 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\\\
\left(\frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}}\right)\cdot 2 &= 2\cdot\left(\frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}}\right)\left(\frac{\text{adj}}{\text{hyp}}\right)\\\\
\frac{1}{3}\cdot 2 & = 2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\\\\
\frac{2}{3} &\neq \frac{4}{9}
\end{align*}$$

Where did I go wrong?
How do the double-angle identities work?

Comment: $\sin(2\theta)$ does not equal $\sin(\theta)\times2$!

Comment: Alright, I'll keep this in mind. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see how the identities work is to see WHY they work. I find that formulas are much more illuminating when one sees a proof. This will, in trigonometry, usually appeal to some geometric intuition while giving you a general formula. So, we can try to prove an identity such as 
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a).$$
Then, using this general formula, what would we know about $\sin(2a)=\sin(a+a)$?

*For a [proof](http://www.themathpage.com/aTrig/sum-proof.htm) of the general angle sum formula, here is a fairly nice geometric approach which you may find illuminating.*

Comment: Yes! This was exactly what I needed and I will definitely read this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also, a right triangle with those sides does not exist due to Pythagorean Theorem.

If you need to check the formula then take for instance $\theta = \pi /2$. Then $\sin(2\theta) = \sin(\pi) = 0$. On the other hand, $2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)= 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0=0$.

Comment: Alright, but could you explain how the identities work, preferably using mathematical examples? Thanks!

Comment: O' my brain finally caught on with what you said *facepalms*.. Thanks for your help!